# Copy/set object from the list of objects to another object from the same class

Tags: c#, list, object

I want to copy/set object from list of object to another object from the same class.
I am doing quiz game and I have there QuestionBase class in which I store all questions. I store it in this list.

```
public List<Question> questionsList = new List<Question>();
```

And then in another class I created QuestionBase class object, and Question currentQuestion object in which I will put current question.
Can I and how assign to this currentQuestion object this object from list? Like this:

```
currentQuestion=questionBaseObject.questionsList[0];
```

It doesn't work... I am doing this wrong or it isn't even possible?

Comment: You should read about static members, Singleton pattern and inheritance. Either of those might help.you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to have a `public static` member for you currentQuestion. 
Public static members can be accessed from other classes

I suggest uploading your code to CodeReview to get the best solution for your implementation